# Advanced tag filtering not working for more than one tags selected in same collection

Tags: filtering, shopify, liquid

The problem I'm having right now is related to advanced filtering in shopify theme "Fashe"

I have made certain filter groups in my store using advanced filtering by group option. But when i choose a filter in one category, I want other filters to be updated as well related to that category.

Like If i choose collection type to be of one kind, i want the collection colors to be related to those kind only. right now it shows me all the colors available in my store. If choosing one filter, it should change the values in other filters also based on the collection type.

If somebody has this issue resolved, I would be very much pleased if you help me with this.

**SECOND THING**

One more issue is when I select filter A, the theme gives me the results associated with that filter but when i click Filter B (filter A being selected already) the theme gives me no results instead it shows that no products matching. Somebody with this issue???

Example: www.mytheme/collections/fine/opt1+opt2
This works as an AND statement. But I want to show results from both, opt1 and opt2.

Shopify should work with OR statements. Like combined results of filter A and Filter B.

Comment: You should split this question into 2 and ask separately.

Comment: BTW, Shopify standard collection filtering by tags in URL (tag1+tag2) doesn't support **OR** operator. It filters with **AND**

Comment: @vladimir thanks for the reply. But this problem is a valid one. okay forget the first question. What about second condition. Any other alternative?

Comment: @Vladimir My store has many collections. And upto 2000+ products. I want my customer to view one collection by clicking on the tag given in the list, but if they want to see another one also they can do that without canceling out the fist one. The url then produced it www../.../fine/opt1+opt2.

This is not working in my case. The output is sorry no products found. Though the answer should be a combined answer for opt1+opt2. This is what Im asking basically. OR Condition. Any other alternative?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy solution for that. You can try some apps from the Shopify app store. Another alternative is to create automatic collections based on **OR** conditions with different tags combinations. You will get a collection itself and you would need to add links to the created collections in your templates.

Comment: this would require multiple tag passed to a function different time. Right now i have just one AJAX request pushing it. But, still, thanks alot for the help.

I know there are plugins for that, but i wanted a solution myself. Don't want to put any plugin.